# What tagger (and training) is best for casual communication; in a web server?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to tag tweets, texts (from mobiles) and email. I found these concerns which are specific to these kinds of communications:

- modern language, full of verbs; some corpora seem very bad with verbs
- brief communications with bad punctuation and fragments of sentences
- new words "The **Jelly Bean** version" or "the **BYOD** movement" or "yout bank **bal** is"

I want a tagger that is robust to such "less than eloquent" text and is still fast and resource-efficient for a real-time web server.

Which tagger (and corpus) is the best choice for this?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but you can take a look at this [here](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/)

Comment: I haven't tried it either, but you could try training a tagger on the NPS Chat Corpus that is included in NLTK.

Answer (score 0):

Most POS taggers used the Penn Treebank tagset, which was proposed by
(Marcus, Santorini, & Ann, 1993)
Penn Treebank tagset contains 36 different labels for parts of speech.

However this set is not suitable for performing POS tagging on tweets, because of the lack of
conventional orthography, and the limits of 140 characters (Gimpel, et al., 2011)
.
Gimpel has implemented a POS tagging for Twitter with their own tagset, which contains some specific
features. These features ensure the tagging consistency over tweets
(Gimpel, et al., 2011) and they are
listed as below:

### Twitter orthography: for detecting @

mentions, hashtags and URLs Names (frequently capitalized tokens): users can have various ways using capitalization because there are not any agreements in writing tweets

Metaph (phonetic normalization): for normalizing many alternate spelling of words. E.g. {thanks,
thanksss, thnx,...} stand for the word “thank”
Their tagger is a conditional random field (CRF)
(Lafferty, McCallum, & Pereira, 2001)

. CRFs are class of statistical methods for pattern recognition and machine learning. The main difference between CRF and other classifiers is that CRF also considers the context while the others do not take context into
account.

This derived characteristic from CRF and the enhancements on the tagset improved the adaptability of
their tagger to the twitter domain and therefore they achieved a better accuracy in comparison with
Stanford tree tagger in their experiment (89.
39% compares to 85.85%).

Admitting the fact that the approach outperformed current methods, the substantial challenges still
remain i.e. the misclassification from a non -standard capitalization to a proper noun, or from rare tokens including obscure symbols to the miscellaneous category.
(Gimpel, et al., 2011)

Ref: [Evaluation of NaturalLanguage Processing Techniques for Sentiment Analysis on Tweets](http://www.ke.tu-darmstadt.de/lehre/arbeiten/bachelor/2012/Dang_Thanh_Tung.pdf)